# For In Person Signer type, the Recipient Signer Name cannot be blank

Tags: docusignapi

I'm suddenly getting this error message when I try to instantiate an envelope from a template:

```
text: '{\r\n  "errorCode": "IN_PERSON_SIGNER_NAME_CANNOT_BE_BLANK",\r\n  "message": "For In Person Signer type, the Recipient Signer Name cannot be blank."\r\n}',
```

This is the code I'm using to create TemplateRoles:

```
  const tRole = new docusign.TemplateRole();
  tRole.setRoleName(templateRoleName);
  tRole.setName(signerName);
  tRole.setEmail(signerEmail);

  tRole.setInPersonSignerName(signerName);
  tRole.setDefaultRecipient('true');
  tRole.setClientUserId('agent');
  templateRolesList.push(tRole);

  // Create a tempalte role for each client
  // TODO: Set correct user data where appropriate instead of test data
  let count = 1;
  forEach(opts.contacts, () => {
    const clientRole = new docusign.TemplateRole();
    clientRole.setRoleName(`client${count}`);
    clientRole.setName(signerName);
    clientRole.setEmail(signerEmail);

    clientRole.setInPersonSignerName(signerName);
    clientRole.setDefaultRecipient('true');
    clientRole.setClientUserId(`client${count}`);

    templateRolesList.push(clientRole);
    count++;
  });

  console.log('templateRolesList', JSON.stringify(templateRolesList));
```

From that console log, I get:

```
[
  {
    "email": "eng@residenetwork.com",
    "roleName": "agent",
    "name": "Reside Network",
    "signingGroupId": null,
    "inPersonSignerName": "Reside Network",
    "clientUserId": "agent",
    "embeddedRecipientStartURL": null,
    "defaultRecipient": "true",
    "accessCode": null,
    "routingOrder": null,
    "emailNotification": null,
    "tabs": null
  },
  {
    "email": "eng@residenetwork.com",
    "roleName": "client1",
    "name": "Reside Network",
    "signingGroupId": null,
    "inPersonSignerName": "Reside Network",
    "clientUserId": "client1",
    "embeddedRecipientStartURL": null,
    "defaultRecipient": "true",
    "accessCode": null,
    "routingOrder": null,
    "emailNotification": null,
    "tabs": null
  }
]
```

In these objects, inPersonSignerName is set to "Reside Network".  I don't understand why this error is appearing or what it is complaining about.

Our code has not changed (though its possible some setting in our account has).

Answer (score 3):

For `inPersonSigners` the name and email of the user hosting the signing are required, and the name of the signer is required whereas their email is optional.

For example:

```
"inPersonSigners": [{
    "hostEmail": "john.doe@company.com",
    "hostName": "John Doe",
    "autoNavigation": true,
    "defaultRecipient": false,
    "signInEachLocation": false,
    "signerEmail": "optional_signer_email",
    "signerName": "Sally Doe"
}],
```

API Docs for inPersonSigner:
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#inPerson

Comment: Sending this and getting the same error:   {"email":null,"roleName":"client1","name":null,"signingGroupId":null,"inPersonSignerName":"Chris Dzoba","clientUserId":"client1","embeddedRecipientStartURL":null,"defaultRecipient":false,"accessCode":null,"routingOrder":null,"emailNotification":null,"tabs":null,"hostEmail":"docusign@residenetwork.com","hostName":"Reside Network","signerName":"Chris Dzoba","autonavigation":true}