# Cant apply template role for in person signer [Java]

Tags: docusignapi

I've seen a similar problem at [For In Person Signer type, the Recipient Signer Name cannot be blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926377/for-in-person-signer-type-the-recipient-signer-name-cannot-be-blank)

But the answer given isn't helping me because I can't figure out how to add those values shown in the json via my javacode

So I'm assigning these template roles to an existing template and its been working fine. I decided to make the CustomerPOD a in person signer. From what I'm seeing the only thing that has to do with in person signer is the SetInPersonSignerName which you figure would set the in person signer name haha.

Unfortunately it seems like I'm missing something as the following error below is thrown.

Any help would be much appreciated as I haven't found a solution anywhere on these threads. Thanks a ton!

```
      TemplateRole tRoleHR = new TemplateRole();
      tRoleHR.setRoleName(title1);
      tRoleHR.setName(name1);
      tRoleHR.setEmail(email1);
      tRoleHR.setRoutingOrder("1");

      TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();
      tRole.setRoleName(title3);
      tRole.setName(name3);
      tRole.setEmail(email3);
      tRole.setRoutingOrder("3");

      TemplateRole tRoleService = new TemplateRole();
      tRoleService.setRoleName(title2);
      tRoleService.setName(name2);
      tRoleService.setEmail(email2);
      tRoleService.setRoutingOrder("2");

      TemplateRole tRoleDriver = new TemplateRole();
      tRoleDriver.setRoleName(title4);
      tRoleDriver.setName(name4);
      tRoleDriver.setEmail(email4);
      tRoleDriver.setRoutingOrder("4");

      TemplateRole tRoleCustomerPOD = new TemplateRole();
      tRoleCustomerPOD.setRoleName(title5);
      tRoleCustomerPOD.setName(name5);
      tRoleCustomerPOD.setEmail(email5);
      tRoleCustomerPOD.setRoutingOrder("5");
      tRoleCustomerPOD.setInPersonSignerName("Joe Customer");
```

Exception: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{
"errorCode": "IN_PERSON_SIGNER_NAME_CANNOT_BE_BLANK",
"message": "For In Person Signer type, the Recipient Signer Name cannot be blank."

Comment: does your template have an In-Person signer role?

Answer (score 0):

For in person signers you need to call these two extra methods:

```
setHostName("Host Name");
setHostEmail("hostemail@email.com");
```

These set the host, which is a separate person from the signer in the case of "in person signer"